# Computing $\Phi_i(X)\in\mathbb F_3[X], i=1,\ldots,6$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

I want to calculate the first six cyclotomic polynomials over $\mathbb F_3$; e.g,
$$
\Phi_i(X)\in\mathbb F_3[X],\; i=1,\ldots,6.
$$

How is this different to computing cyclotomic polynomials over $\mathbb Q$, for $1$ to $6$ I cannot reduce the coefficients because they are all $\pm1$...

Comment: Beats me :-) May be your book/teacher wants you to factor the usual cyclotomic polynomials in $\Bbb{F}_3[x]$. Otherwise this looks like a futile exercise.